# How to hide URL link on hover in Outlook

Tags: javascript, html, css, outlook, hyperlink

I've made a email template in HTML for Outlook and it includes a button, when the user clicks the button it navigates to a website. I'm trying to hide the URL link when the user hovers over it.

When I test the template using Google Chrome the URL doesn't appear and when you click on the button it goes to the website but when I send the template in Outlook, you can't see the link when you hover over it but when I click on the button it doesn't go to the website.

I'm fairly new at this, so was wondering it anyone could help. The code I'm currently using is:

```
<a onclick="location.href='IP Address'">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible (thankfully, since support for this would be a great boon to phishers).

Email clients that accept HTML formatted mail do not accept JavaScript.